# ionic start myApp sidemenu not working

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic start myApp sidemenu not working. It's not creating a side menu template. Instead, it creates blank template (Which will happen only if we run ionic start myApp blank). Anybody have an idea about what is wrong?

Comment: same problem but dont know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it's not working, but i downloaded it from this link, which solves my problem

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu

Comment: Now it's working while trying 'ionic start myApp sidemenu'

Comment: this one miss the lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Clean Cache

```
npm cache clean
```

Then Command

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

It Works For me.

I have found some empty json files in cache folder.